# Hbase how to do sorting by timestamp

Tags: hbase

All I want to get from data in HBase e.g.between two timestamp and also all data should be sorted by timestamp

First I want to do it in Hbase shell to try the performance.

In RDBMS query could be like

Select column1,column2 from table where start_date >
 timestamp and end_date < timestamp order by start_date desc limit 10

Desc order is most important here any way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance would not be good at all - you'd have to scan every single row in the table to find all those between the relevant timestamps, and then sort the results. Sorting is not possible in HBase shell.

Consider a secondary index table with the timestamp as the key, linking back to the primary table.

As an alternative, look at Apache Phoenix for SQL-like functionality over HBase.

Comment: Thanks Ben Watson. This is helpful one question phoenix will also gave same perfrormance [ Assume we donot create secondary table with timestamp as key]

Comment: Phoenix should be faster as it contains under-the-hood optimisations and can generate indexes for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can even use Apache Drill to do sql query on Hbase.

For Hbase Shell you can use

```
scan 't1', { TIMERANGE => [0, 1416083300000] }
```

Here t1 => name of the table
Time range is epoch time

If you can code and find go for this link

```
https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/io/TimeRange.html
```

It has all the available functions you are looking forward.